# What is the most complete book of integrals and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, definite-integrals, book-recommendation, reference-works

I'm looking for something like "If it's not in this book, it's not known".

I've got a copy of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, which seems *pretty* good. But I'm hoping there are some better ones out there.

Comment: Gradshteyn and Ryzhik made an outstanding book, not just a pretty one. For which purpose do you need something "better" ?

Comment: The Bronstein is very famous : http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Mathematics-I-N-Bronshtein/dp/3540721215/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1/183-1176460-8324725?ie=UTF8&qid=1434118227&sr=8-1-fkmr2&keywords=Bornstein+Handbook+of+Mathematics. Some people say Bornstein-integrable which means if this integral could not be performed by the rules of the book of Bornstein than it is not integrable in our case

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to ask this [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Boris Pavlovich Demidovich.-(5000) Problems in Mathematical Analysis.
You could have a really good time.
Also
Theory And Application Of Infinite Series
by Knopp,Konrad.

Answer (score 1):

As the most complete collection I would suggest the 4-volume set *Integrals and series* by A. P. Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov and O. I. Marichev:

- I - Elementary functions,
- II - Special functions,
- III - More special functions,
- IV - Laplace transforms.