# Closed form for ${\large\int}_0^\pi\frac{x\,\cos\frac x3}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form for the integral below and I found the following conjecture using computer search (and some lucky guesses):
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{x\,\cos\frac x3}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}dx\stackrel{\color{#A0A0A0}?}=\frac{\pi\sqrt[3]2}{24}\big(7\pi\sqrt3-9\ln3\big).\tag1$$
Could you please help me to find a proof of it?

Comment: @Joelafrite The integral converges for the original integrand since as $x\to \pi$,  $(\sin x)^{1/3}\sim (\pi-x)^{1/3}$.  And we know that $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(\pi-x)^{1/3}}$ converges.

Comment: In general, $$\int_0^\pi\sin(2ax)~\sin^{2n}x~dx ~=~ \frac{\pi\cdot\sin(\pi a)}{4^n}\cdot{2n\choose n\pm a}$$

Comment: @Lucian, are you aware if it is straightforwardly possible to analytical continue your formula to non-integer $n$?

Comment: @tired: When did I ever say that *n* is an integer ?

Comment: @Lucian: When i see an "$n$"  i just tend to believe that we have an integer but never mind

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I wrote in my [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1323540/73025), the most complete reference for various integrals is Prudnikov-Brychkov-Marichev. Here it suffices to use the formula 2.5.12.36 from Vol. 1:
$$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{\mu-1}x\sin bx\,dx=\frac{2^{1-\mu}\pi\Gamma\left(\mu\right) \sin \frac{b\pi}{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\mu+1-b}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\mu+1+b}{2}\right)}.\tag{1}$$
(For the proof, make the change of variables $t=e^{2i x}$ in $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi}e^{ibx}\sin^{\mu-1}x\,dx$ and shrink the resulting integration contour to the branch cut $t\in[0,1]$.)

Differentiating (1) with respect to $b$, we obtain
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi}x\sin^{\mu-1}x\cos bx\,dx=\\=&\,\frac{2^{-\mu}\pi\Gamma\left(\mu\right) }{\Gamma\left(\frac{\mu+1-b}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\mu+1+b}{2}\right)}\left\{\pi\cos\frac{\pi b}{2}+\left[\psi\left(\frac{\mu+1-b}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\mu+1+b}{2}\right)\right]\sin\frac{b\pi}{2}\right\}.
\end{align}
Setting $b=\frac13$, $\mu=\frac23$ and using that [$\psi\left(\frac23\right)-\psi\left(1\right)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}-9\ln 3}{6}$](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/03/01/0009/) (in fact the digamma function of *any* rational argument has an [elementary expression](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/03/01/0013/)) yields
$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\cos\frac{x}{3}\,dx}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}=2^{-\frac23}\pi\left\{\pi\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}-9\ln 3}{12}\right\},$$
which is equivalent to the conjectured result.